# os sites pwa funcionan no iphone como no android?

Tags: html5, ios, iphone, pwa, webdesign

Boa noite a todos!!!

A minha dúvida é a seguinte: sites feitos com PWA funcionam da mesma forma no iphone e ipad, como no android?
é necessária alguma alteração para iphone?

Sem mais, obrigado pela atenção!!!

Comment: Recomendo: https://www.opus-software.com.br/pwa-no-ios/

Comment: vou ler com calma, mas assim, apenas a instalação do mesmo, por exemplo, fixar na tela inicial, como um app, (como faço no android) é possível sem grandes problemas?
Vou ler o conteúdo agora mesmo, obrigado!

Answer (score 1):

Sim amigo existem uma série de cuidados a ser tomados quando o PWA vai rodar no iOS.

O primeiro é que para sava-lo como atalho na tela inicial vc precisa identificar qual é o browser de acesso para descobrir se é o Safari e ai instruir o usuário do procedimento correto para salvar o PWA localmente.

Sobre o ícone do App vc vai precisar de um link no `<head>` com  `rel="apple-touch-icon"` para definir a imagem do ícone.

```
<link rel="apple-touch-icon" href="/custom_icon.png">
```

Outro ponto é que a tela de carregamento padrão costuma ser branca, o que não da um feedback para o usuário. Para tratar isso se usa a tag um link `rel="apple-touch-startup-image"` no tb no `<head>` do documento para durante o carregamento mostrar uma imagem e não a tela branca.

```
<meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes" />
<link href="/apple_splash_2048.png" sizes="2048x2732" rel="apple-touch-startup-image" />
```

Aqui vc pode consultar o guia de desenvolvimento e outras tags exclusivas para dispositivo Apple https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/AppleApplications/Reference/SafariWebContent/ConfiguringWebApplications/ConfiguringWebApplications.html

Além disso existem vários outros cuidados a serem tomados, recomendo que leia esse artigo https://medium.com/@oieduardorabelo/pwa-no-ios-como-deix%C3%A1-lo-mais-nativo-e022f6c67b9c